# Prevent selecting all available options in jQuery ASM select

Tags: jquery, asmselect

In [this page](http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/examples/example1.html) - when you start to type the city name 'hong..' instead of selecting from the drop down,  both 'Hong Kong' and 'Honolulu' gets selected (sometimes 'Houston' too depending how fast you type in).

Can anyone help me prevent selecting both - not to select any until I enter 4 characters ? TIA

this is the library I use http://www.ryancramer.com/projects/asmselect/jquery.asmselect.js

From my page I call

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select[multiple]").asmSelect({
            addItemTarget: 'bottom',
            animate: true,
            highlight: true,
            sortable: true
        });

    }); 

</script>
<select id="cities" multiple="multiple" name="cities[]" title="Click to Select a City">
                    <option>Amsterdam</option>      
                    <option>Atlanta</option>
                    <option>Baltimore</option>
                    <option>Boston</option>
                    <option>Buenos Aires</option>
                    <option>Calgary</option>
                    <option>Chicago</option>
                    <option>Denver</option>
                    <option>Dubai</option>
                    <option>Frankfurt</option>
                    <option>Hong Kong</option>
                    <option>Honolulu</option>
                    <option>Houston</option>
                    <option>Kuala Lumpur</option>
                    <option>London</option>
                    <option>Los Angeles</option>
                    <option>Melbourne</option>
                    <option>Mexico City</option>
                    <option>Miami</option>
                    <option>Minneapolis</option>
                    <option>Montreal</option>
                    <option>New York City</option>
                    <option>Paris</option>
                    <option>Philadelphia</option>
                    <option>Rotterdam</option>
                    <option>San Diego</option>
                    <option>San Francisco</option>
                    <option>Sao Paulo</option>
                    <option>Seattle</option>
                    <option>Seoul</option>
                    <option>Shanghai</option>
                    <option>Singapore</option>
                    <option>Sydney</option>
                    <option>Tokyo</option>
                    <option>Toronto</option>
                    <option>Vancouver</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! It would help if you showed the relevant javascript code that you use for the select function.

Answer (score 0):

But this compoment dont have a input text for you tip, just multiple select.To jQuery I use a light library with name autoComplete, check for see [auto-complete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)